# dynamically add row on click of fileupload showing file details

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I want to populate the table dynamically with the filename, filesize and some operations like delete the file once the user selects the file to upload, showing details of the file selected to upload, in a table format using jsp, javascript or jquery. Please suggest.Thanks.

--EDITED--
I have tried the below code, but i'am not sure how to get the file size and perform delete operation without the upload has not yet performed.Whenever user choose the file the details of the file should be shown in the table below.  Please find the similar scenario in http://jsfiddle.net/s98Tw/2/.

JSP code:

```
     <table border="1">
         <tr>
                <th>SNo</th><th>FileName</th><th>FileSize</th><th>Action</th> </tr>
                <tr><td><input type="text" name="sno" id="sno"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fileName" id="fileName"/></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="fileSize" id="fileSize"/></td>
                    <td><a href="delete">Delete</a></input></td>
        </tr>

         </table>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function addFileData(field){
   var file_name = document.getElementById("file1").value;
    document.getElementById("fileName").value=file_name;
}
```

Comment: "the table" refers to...? A table you have on your page? Put some code in your post. Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: I agree with Nick! We can't do much to help you out if you don't give us something to work with...

Comment: @NickDugger , Please see the modified code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **EDIT:**

Here is a new [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/s98Tw/3/)

You should be able to take from that what you need. I didn't know what 'sno' was so I left it out, but it should be pretty similar to the other two!

You should look into `window.File`, `window.FileReader`, `window.FileList`, and `window.Blob`. Those objects will contain what you're looking for to gather information on a file before it is uploaded. The rest of the table manipulation is simple javascript code on the front end.

One good source might be [**this**](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/)

---

### **OLD STUFF:**

Despite the lack of detail, here is what I came up with... I hope it helps... [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jlaw/VnfgL/1/)

I would suggest that you look into the JQuery documentation for the  [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) function. That is one way you can dynamically add an element to the DOM. Also, the [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function is very useful for providing a way to bind an element to a click action such as a delete funciton, or a function to display details.

Please try to find your own understanding of these concepts before you copy and paste anything.

Also, Stack Overflow is meant to provide answers to ['practical, detailed questions.'](https://stackoverflow.com/about). Please keep that in mind for the future.